# Resource Closing concern wih finally block

Tags: java, exception

In my code, there is a memory Leak, due to some uncleaned resource issue, so I am currently closing those resources in finally block, as I know finally always executed.

In many functions I m returning the same resource, which will I gonna close in the finally block and my understanding is that first the return statement of try or catch is computed based on exception and then the finally will close the resource and then the resource which is computed above will returned, please share your views that I m right or wrong.

and one more query, that If there is no exception handling in some function of my code would i use try with finally is this is the good choice or try with catch with finally

Posting some codes for the second and third situation.

```
public Set<> processMessage(Object message) throws Exception {
        HtmlPage Page = null;
        try{
            Page = getPage();
            return inPage.getWebClient().getCookieManager().getCookies();
            }
        finally
        {   
            if(Page!=null)
            Page.cleanUp();
        }

    }
```

and In third situation If I have to return the HtmlPage which is processed inside the method like

```
        public HtmlPage simulate(HtmlElement element,
            MyContext context) {

try{

        HtmlPage Page = null;
        //getting the page here and suppose that there are various condition on the basis of this Page value is //evaluated and returned in some situation. 

        return Page;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(Page!=null)
            Page.cleanUp();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Post your code. Returning a closed resource looks like a pretty bad idea: what will the caller do with the returned resource if it's closed?

Comment: If you're using the resource only for processing and returning the result after the processing done on the resource and not returning the resource itself, then closing the resources in finally block is okay, otherwise not

Comment: @ambigram_maker well i thought `try/finally` was a perfect construct to use in many situations where the exceptions cant be handled locally ;-) when you want the exception to be handled at above layers but don't want to leave the open resources mess, it makes perfect sense, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah... you need to close the resource right?

Comment: yup, closing the resource :)

Comment: Then I think you should reserve a way to ***`throw`*** the `Exception` if you can't handle it.

Comment: @JB Nizet, My friend what I have studied that the return statement is computed before closing the resource , is I m wrong , and if this is not the good way then what is the best way to deal with this situations

Comment: @dreamer In my code I have an HtmlPage and in the function I have done some processing over that page like get the enclosedWindows from it and then returning the HTMLElement Object from these windows and at that time I m closing the HTmlPage in the finally block so this is not the good way

Comment: The situation is extremely vague, because you haven't posted any code. So we have to guess what you're actually doing. Post your code, and we'll be able to tell you how to best handle your concrete problem.

Comment: @JB Nizet, My friend I have just added some code

Comment: In the second case, I assume that the caller wants to do something with the page, and that he won't be able to do it if the page had been cleaned up. The finally block will clean up the page before the caller can use it, so that's not what you should do. The caller should clean up the page instead.

Comment: @ambigram_maker If the `exception` is not caught at some level, then its automatically sent up the layers, i mean the callers so that they could handle it. think of it as the `chain of responsibility` design pattern.

Comment: @JB Nizet, As I know that return is computed first, so the return statement is stored somewhere in the memory and then finally clean the resource and then it return the result which is computed above, so the Page is returnd to the HtmlPage reference of caller and caller can do anything with the reference holding the returned object

Comment: The method returns a reference to the page object. And this page object has been cleaned up by the finally block when the caller receives the reference to this object.